# How do I prevent my Rails application from attack?

Tags: authentication, penetration-test, html, rails, ruby

My website is being nuked by new signups and new posts some of which don't even have user.id associated with.

How do I solve this? What code should I add to the user#new page and/or post#new page.

If it would help, please check my repo: https://github.com/nixor/cpblog

Comment: you posted your project without posting the location of the vulnerable code.  I'm going to dig around in your project.  You should be more helpful.

Comment: Also who cares if they use curl,  they could be using netcat or python httplib.  That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not looked into your code, but the things I would do are:

- checking the eligibility of the user to do anything on your website before making that user makes an action. (If somebody posting something without even registering in the site - it is no good).
- to prevent from the new signup the common practice is to confirm yourself using a mail account or an account from high profile resources google acount, fb account.